# Enable standby mode when the phone case lid is closed

Tags: lock-screens, screen, standby

I have a tablet (Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1) and a phone (Google Nexus 5X) both with CyanogenMod as ROM. When I close the lid of the case on the tablet, it automatically turns off the screen (and locks after some time). However, the phone stays active until the display timeout.

1. Is there a special setting or some hardware sensor which is not present in the phone or maybe difference in Android versions for phones and tablets?
2. I searched a bit and found app recommendations with the warning, that they will drain the battery. But when it's enabled in CyanogenMod, it should work on both devices without any apps, shouldn't it?
3. So is there some setting, does it depend on sensors, maybe the case (the tablet one closes with a small magnet, but I guess the proximity or brightness sensor should toggle the screen) or what else can be the cause for different behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus 5X does have a Hall sensor responsible for magnetic "smart covers" to work. Either your cover itself doesn't contain such a magnet piece (downcost), or CM for your device hasn't included support for it.

Remember that although CM seems to be the same on every devices, they depend on vastly different, device-specific underlying codes, and are maintained by independent people, so it's very possible for one hardware feature to be present in a device but not in another. For example, my own Note 10.1 2014 (SM-P607T), although already in the queue of official CM13 nightlies, actually has borked Hall sensor support too.

Comment: my tablet is a note 10.1 2014 as well, but with cm for android 4.4 (had no cm13 support when installing). So CM does this with the hall sensor alone, no light sensor? The smartphone cover does not have a magnet, so this would be the explanation. I hoped it would use light and/or proximity as well.

Comment: Yes the native implementation always use Hall sensors, mainly to conserve battery and I guess also to avoid coding unnecessary workarounds.

Comment: Does it matter, to which side the lid closes (because of the hall sensor position)? I see that there are quite a few cases which open from top to bottom, but i would prefer one, which opens from right to left.

Comment: @allo Side doesn't matter, the magnet is always placed at the location of the Hall sensor when the lid is closed.